# Calculate size of SparkR dataframe

Tags: sparkr

I have a dataframe I got by making a query using a **SQLContext**:

```
> df <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT * FROM myTable")
```

when I try to get its size

```
> object.size(df)
1024 bytes
```

I know that it is not the real size of the dataframe, probably because it's distributed over Spark nodes. To get the real size I need to **collect** it:

```
> localDf <- collect(df)
> object.size(localDf)
45992 bytes
```

Sometimes the dataframe is too big to fit in the local memory. Is there a simple way to know the actual size of a dataframe without bringing it locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a satisfactory workaround for this problem. I set the following [Spark configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties) to load the SparkContext:

```
spark.driver.maxResultSize=1m
```

In this case, when the result is bigger than 1MB, spark will return a **org.apache.spark.SparkException**, so I caught it and returned an error message.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the Spark Web UI. Under the Executors tab you can look at Storage Memory.

Comment: That's a solutiion, thanks! However, I needed to know it via code, so then I can avoid getting the dataframe locally.

Comment: Sure. I don't know how you would hook in programmatically, other than setting spark.eventLog.enabled to true or using spark monitoring system's sinks to write out those metrics for you and read them in.